# Show plane sections of the conicoid $ax²+by²+cz²= 1$ which are rectangular hyperbola and which pass through point $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ touch a cone

Tags: conic-sections, 3d, plane-geometry

Show that all plane sections of the conicoid $ax²+by²+cz²= 1$ which are rectangular hyperbolas and which pass through the point $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ touch the cone
$\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{b+c}$+$\frac{(y-\beta)^2}{c+a}$+$\frac{(z-\gamma)^2}{a+b}$=0

**My attempt**

Given equation of comicoid is $ax²+by²+cz²= 1$
Let $lx+my+nz=0$ be a plane which cuts the conicoid in rectangular hyperbolas. Therefore,

$(b+c)l² + (c+a)m² + (a+b)n² = 0$ ..........(1)

Now the plane passes through the point $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$. Therefore
l$\alpha$+m$\beta$+n$\gamma$=0

Hence we can write the equation of plane as $lx+my+nz =$ l$\alpha$+m$\beta$+n$\gamma$

or, l(x-$\alpha$)+m(y-$\beta$)+n(z-$\gamma$)=0 ....... (2)
I don't know how to proceed further please help me

Comment: I don't understand: sections of an elllipsoid can never be hyperbolas, for instance. Hence coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ cannot be arbitrary. Are you sure the text is correct?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca conicoid not "ellipsoid" see my question

Comment: An ellipsoid is a particular conicoid, obtained for instance with $a=b=c=1$ (which is also a sphere).

Comment: @Intelligentipauca i know that but this type of examples are given in my text book and this question is right

Comment: @Intelligentipauca My guess is that we are supposed to interpret the equation as "if $ax^2 + bx^2 + cx^2 = 1$ has sections which are rectangular hyperbolae, show that these hyperbolae touch the cone."  But I agree that the phrasing of the question is very awkward and confusing.